# jquery scrollTop does not work in IE8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, scrolltop

I'm trying to scroll the page based on the hash on the url. Here's my code:

```
var hash = window.location.hash;
$(hash).scrollTop();
```

This doesn't to anything. So what am I doing wrong?
And another thing, I need something like this:

```
$(hash).scrollTop($("#header").height());
```

Is that possible?..is my div(the element hash is pointed to) going to scroll to the top, upto the bottom of the `"#header"`?..

## Update 1

The hash text is an id so it returns the text "#myid" from `window.location.hash`. One other thing, the div of the header has a `position:fixed` on its css while the container where the div(the hash is id'd to) has a `position:absolute` so it is scrolling under the `#header` that's why I need it to scroll to the bottom of the header or the height.

## Update 2

I'm now trying to use the [scrollIntoView() plugin](https://github.com/Arwid/jQuery.scrollIntoView) but having the error.

```
Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)
Timestamp: Mon, 17 Oct 2011 03:23:18 UTC


Message: Object doesn't support this property or method
Line: 71
Char: 5
Code: 0
URI: http://localhost:3000/javascripts/jquery.scrollIntoView.js


Message: Object doesn't support this property or method
Line: 34
Char: 5
Code: 0
URI: http://localhost:3000/surveys/%E6%83%85%E5%A0%B1%E3%82%BB%E3%82%AD%E3%83%A5%E3%83%AA%E3%83%86%E3%82%A3%E3%83%BB%E5%80%8B%E4%BA%BA%E6%83%85%E5%A0%B1%E4%BF%9D%E8%AD%B7%E3%83%81%E3%82%A7%E3%83%83%E3%82%AF%E3%82%B7%E3%83%BC%E3%83%88%EF%BC%88%E8%87%AA%E5%B7%B1%E7%82%B9%E6%A4%9C%EF%BC%89-%E7%89%88-1-0/C9uKCqXNn2/take?section=17
```

My code is: `$("#survey_section_8").scrollIntoView();`

what am I doing wrong here?..

Hope that I was clear in my questions. Thank you!

Comment: Try This

IE Scroll Not Working - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6736849/scrolltop-not-working-in-ie/7804393#7804393

Comment: It's just like before. It is scrolling to the top most of the page, anyways may be I just don't give the correct values to it. xP Thanks for the link!

Comment: I'd just like to add: of course it doesn't work in IE8. nothing does.

Comment: Why not use the non-JS scroll. For example: [#copyright](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7762114/jquery-scrolltop-does-not-work-in-ie8#copyright) added to this url should jump to the copyright section of this page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using [this plugin jQuery.ScrollTo()](http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/). But still I can't get rid off that error. So I tried putting my code inside the javascript of the plugin. Eureka! it worked! I think the error is caused by the other jquery inside the page. This is what I have inserted in the javascript:

```
jQuery(function( $ ){
                //borrowed from jQuery easing plugin
                //http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery.easing.php
                $.easing.elasout = function(x, t, b, c, d) {
                        var s=1.70158;var p=0;var a=c;
                        if (t==0) return b;  if ((t/=d)==1) return b+c;  if (!p) p=d*.3;
                        if (a < Math.abs(c)) { a=c; var s=p/4; }
                        else var s = p/(2*Math.PI) * Math.asin (c/a);
                        return a*Math.pow(2,-10*t) * Math.sin( (t*d-s)*(2*Math.PI)/p ) + c + b;
                };

                $(document).ready(function(){
                    $.scrollTo(window.location.hash, {speed:800, easing:'swing',axis:'y',offset:{top:-(parseInt($('#header').height()))}});
                });
            });
```

I know this isn't the best answer. But it did the job, so it's alright! I'll figure it out later on how to optimize it.

Answer (score 4):

You need something more like this to scroll to the specified anchor:

```
var y = $('a[name=' + window.location.hash + ']').offset().top;
$("html, body").scrollTop(y);
```

Note that you'll need some text within that `<a>` (e.g. just a space) to be able to get the `offset`.

Comment: The `window.location.hash` returns the id of my div, sorry for the confusion. But that still didn't work. It scrolls to the top most of the page. _See my updated question_

Comment: $("html, body") is key for compliance with IE8

Answer (score 0):

`$(window.location.hash)` isn't going to do you much, because that's just a string. jQuery needs more instruction to find the element you're looking for.

Is the hash text the id or class or name of an element on the page? You're probably going to need to prefix it with a "." or a "#" or in combination with some other selector in order for jQuery to find the anchor element that generated the hash.

Secondly, calling [`.scrollTop()`](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/) without any parameters *returns* the scroll-top position; it doesn't scroll to the top. Passing a parameter to it sets the vertical scroll position for the element it was called on. @N Rohler's answer is much closer to a working example than I could have come up with off the top of my head. It should be a good start for you.